# Android listview/textview layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview

I'm new to android and trying to put the pieces together for my application. I'm struggling with finding a way to move my app information to the other side of the screen. I'm using a custom layout that only has a Listview/TextView and this is being accessed by an ArrayAdapter. Is there a way to achieve my desired result **dynamically?** *ie: listview adds two dynamic TextViews, I'm assuming update the TextViews with a FindById, then add a new row that has a new item, add another two TextViews, etc..* If I need to provide additional information, please let me know.

The first screenshot (A) is how it is currently display. The second screenshot (B) is how I would like it to display.

```
//customListView.xml
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall" />
```

//main.java

where.add("Available Value: \t" + ac.get(1) + "\n" + "Available Cash: \t" + ac.get(2));

where.add("");
mMainListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.custom_listview, where);

Screen shot A:[image: How it currently looks]

Screen shot B: [image: What I want it to look like]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `LinearLayout` and `android:layout_weight` android:layout_weight determines the who will take up empty space. You should use multiple `TextView`s to achieve the output you want.

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="1" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:text="2" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="3" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The output

[image]

For your case:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.test.MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Available Value"        
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="$314.10" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The output is as follows:

[image]

Comment: In the case of the button for "2", what would go in the empty control? Are you saying I would need to create additional TextViews, even though I may not use them?

Comment: @snapplex What do you mean by "empty control"?

Comment: If I use your example, the first button would have "Available value:", the second button would be blank?...and the third button would have $314.10 -- Maybe I'm misinterpreting what you're saying.

Comment: @snapplex It was just an example to demonsrate the use of layout_weight. For your case you should use two TextViews, one for "Available Value", one for "$314.10". The TextView for "Available Value" should have a android:layout_weight="1" and android:layout_width="0dp". The other TextView should have android:layout_width="wrap_content" no layout_weight property. I will update the answer to address your specific issue.

Comment: I was able to duplicate the layout using your example. It only works when it is static, so I'll research how to add items dynamically and update both TextViews in the other layout. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a layout like this, based on `RelativeLayout`

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1">
        <TextView
            android:text="Available cash"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView2" />
        <TextView
            android:text="$314.44"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

For each line, you will need 2 TextViews, one for the text and one for the number. 
So to get your screen, you will need a total of 4 TextViews. 
The text will be aligned left with respect to the parent and the number will be aligned right wrt. the parent.

I have given a sample below, try it out and let me know if it works. You might have to tweak it a little.

```
<RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Available"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Available Value"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/AvailableValue"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/Value"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true”/>

   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvCash"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Available Value"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft=“true"
       android:layout_below=android:id="@id/Available"
/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvCashValue"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/Value"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>


    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: So, it sounds like I would need to dynamically create and realign textViews right before I add additional items to my ListView?

Comment: If the above is a row for each list, you dont have to. You will create a layout for each row of the list and inflate it in the getView() method of the adapter

Comment: You can refer to http://www.android-ios-tutorials.com/android/android-custom-listview-example/